# Creating Tkinter widgets with Objects Button and Window - how to put button created using Button class onto window created with Window class

Tags: python, tkinter

UIconstruction.py

```
import tkinter

class Window:
 
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = None
        self.width = None
        self.title = None

    def setDimensions(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def setTitle(self, title):
        self.title = title

    def GetDimensions(self):
        dimensionsDict = {
            "Height": self.height,
            "Width": self.width
        }

        return dimensionsDict

    def getTitle(self):
        return self.title

    def startWindow(self):
        Window.tk = tkinter.Tk()
        Window.tk.geometry(f"{self.width}x{self.height}")
        Window.tk.title(self.title)
        Window.tk.mainloop()

class Button:

    def __init__(self):
        self.height = None
        self.width = None
        self.label = None
        self.container = None

    def setDimensions(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def GetDimensions(self):
        dimensionsDict = {
            "Height": self.height,
            "Width": self.width
        }

        return dimensionsDict

    def setLabel(self, labelText):
        self.label = labelText

    def getLabel(self):
        return self.label   

    def createButton(self):
        button = tkinter.Button(text = self.label, width = self.width, height = self.height)
```

main.py

```
from UIconstruction import Window, Button

background = Window()
button1 = Button()

background.setDimensions(500, 500)
background.setTitle("Test")
background.startWindow()

button1.setDimensions(100, 100)
button1.setLabel("test")
button1.createButton()
```

What I want is for 'button1' is to be in the window 'background', but I have not been able to figure out how to do this (incorrect attempts omitted)

Is there a way to do this with this setup - if so, how?
If there is not a way to do this like this, how should I be doing it optimally.

I'm a relative python beginner, so I don't know much more than the basics past object oriented support.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This code has many mistakes - and this can make big problem.

First: you should keep `tk.Tk()` as `self.tk` instead of `Window.tk`

Second: you need `backgroud.tk` to assign button. But this makes problem. You have to create `tk.Tk()` before you create `Button()` (to use it as parent for for `Button()`), but you have to run `mainloop()` after adding `Button()` to `Window()` (because `mainloop()` blocks rest of code)

---

You should send it as parameter

```
button1 = Button(background.tk)
```

and keep it in `__init__`

```
class Button:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.height = None
        self.width = None
        self.label = None
        self.container = None

        self.parent = parent
```

and use it when you create real `tk.Button`

```
    def createButton(self):
        button = tkinter.Button(self.parent, text=self.label, width=self.width, height=self.height)   # PEP8: inside `()` use `=` without spaces
```

---

Eventually you could send it directly to `createButton()`

```
    def createButton(self, parent):
        button = tkinter.Button(parent, text=self.label, width=self.width, height=self.height)   # PEP8: inside `()` use `=` without spaces
```

and run it as

```
button1.createButton(background)
```

---

And you have to also use `.pack()`, `.grid()` or `.place()` to show widget in window.

```
    def createButton(self):
        button = tkinter.Button(self.parent, text=self.label, width=self.width, height=self.height)   # PEP8: inside `()` use `=` without spaces
        button.pack()
```

---

Full working code

```
import tkinter

class Window:
 
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = None
        self.width = None
        self.title = None

    def setDimensions(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def setTitle(self, title):
        self.title = title

    def GetDimensions(self):
        dimensionsDict = {
            "Height": self.height,
            "Width": self.width
        }

        return dimensionsDict

    def getTitle(self):
        return self.title

    def create(self):
        self.tk = tkinter.Tk()
        self.tk.geometry(f"{self.width}x{self.height}")
        self.tk.title(self.title)
    
    def startWindow(self):
        self.tk.mainloop()

class Button:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.height = None
        self.width = None
        self.label = None
        self.container = None
        self.parent = parent

    def setDimensions(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def GetDimensions(self):
        dimensionsDict = {
            "Height": self.height,
            "Width": self.width
        }

        return dimensionsDict

    def setLabel(self, labelText):
        self.label = labelText

    def getLabel(self):
        return self.label   

    def create(self):
        self.button = tkinter.Button(self.parent, text=self.label, width=self.width, height=self.height)
        self.button.pack()
        
#from UIconstruction import Window, Button

background = Window()

background.setDimensions(500, 500)
background.setTitle("Test")
background.create()

button1 = Button(background.tk)

button1.setDimensions(100, 100)
button1.setLabel("test")
button1.create()

background.startWindow()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Code would be more useful if you would create window and button in `__init__` and you would use special function to set values in  widgets because in current code you can't use `setLabel` to change text in button after creating it.